# Cursor changed to 'move' type in contenteditable div in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, contenteditable

If you hover or click on element, it will work correctly in firefox and chorome except IE11. In IE11, when you hover on element, cursor becomes 'move'. To write in element, you have to double click on element. When you double click on element, border created around element.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   <table class="table table-bordered">
       <tr>
           <td contenteditable="true">
               <textarea id="adf" class="form-control" cols="6" rows="2"></textarea>
           </td>
           <td contenteditable="true">
               <input type="text" name="abc" class="form-control" />
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

Here is also a link to a jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bsan8p84/3/

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my application in IE11 - did you got any solution or work around ?